# F# cannot post to web api?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, f#, webclient

I have the following code to post to a web api.

```ml
[<CLIMutable>]
type MyModel = { FileName:string; Period:DateTime; DownloadedTime:DateTimeOffset; Url:string; }

let PostDownload (filepath, date, url) = 
  async {
    try
        use client = new HttpClient()
        let content = { FileName = filepath; Period = date; DownloadedTime = DateTimeOffset.Now; Url = url }
        let! response = Async.AwaitTask(client.PostAsJsonAsync("http://localhost:5000/api/DownloadedFiles", content))
    with 
    | ex -> logger.Error(ex, "Exception: " + ex.Message)
  } |> Async.Start
```

The service has the following code and the debugger shows all the fields of `downloadedFile` are the default values (nulls or the minimum values for value types).

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void Post([FromBody]DownloadedFile downloadedFile)
    {
        try
        {
            _context.DownloadedFile.Add(downloadedFile);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { ...... }
    }
```

The fiddler shows the F# code (or `PostAsJsonAsync` cannot handle F# mutable record type?) added `@` at the end of field name?

> {"FileName@":"test","Period@":"2100-01-01T00:00:00","DownloadedTime@":"2016-08-18T15:50:37.5004391-04:00","Url@":"test"}

Comment: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2015/03/19/posting-json-to-an-f-web-api

Comment: Mark's example is worth looking at. This is a "default HttpClient JSON serializer isn't very good" problem, not an F# problem.

Comment: As an alternative to HttpClient, you could look at [FSharp.Data](https://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/Http.html)...

Comment: You could have a look at https://github.com/haf/Http.fs which is written with F# in mind and also has a lot of test-cases for posting files.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know from where you get `HttpClient.PostAsJsonAsync`, because it's not on the version of `HttpClient` I'm currently looking at. Nevertheless, I typically use this extension, which works for me:

```
type HttpClient with
    member this.PostAsJsonAsync (requestUri : string, value : obj) =
        let json = string value
        let content = new StringContent (json)
        content.Headers.ContentType <-
            Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue "application/json"
        this.PostAsync (requestUri, content)
```

Comment: `PostAsJasonAsync` is in HttpClientExtensions: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh944521(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: I tried the code (by using `PostAsync` instead of `PostAsJasonAsync`. But it still fails and the fiddler showed the http post body is `FSI_0004+MyFileModel` now?

Comment: You're seeing the class name (FSI_0004+MyFileModel) because that's what happens when you call ToString() on a class that hasn't overridden that method. Explicitly converting the object to JSON using a library that understands F# Records (such as current versions of JSON.NET) would allow Mark's example to work.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue and lost some hours solving it.
It seems the serializer that is used in HttpClient.PostAsJsonAsync does not handle fsharp types well. The @ symbol issue is also not easily googleable.
Using the following code however seems to work:

```ml
task {
  let content = JObject.FromObject({ Id = "foo" }).ToString()
  let! response = client.PostAsync("url", new StringContent(content, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"))
  return "Hello world"
}
```